# Excel pivot table : rank groups by same sub category

Tags: excel, pivot-table, percentage, rank

In a pivot table I have groups, each group has 5 same sub categories in percentages of the total of each group : cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4 and cat5, as follows :
GroupA = 100%

- cat 1 = 23%
- cat 2 = 12%
- cat 3 = 27%
- cat 4 = 8%
- cat 5 = 30%

I would like to rank these groups in a new column by sub categories aka : "what is the top 10 groups by sub category 2" ?

I tried to filter by sub category but it only ranks inside of each group

Comment: Could you share some sample data and expected results with that? Please use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: | **Group A**  | **100%**  |
|------------- |---------- |
| Cat1         | 23%       |
| Cat2         | 12%       |
| Cat3         | 27%       |
| Cat4         | 8%        |
| Cat5         | 30%       |
| **Group B**  | **100%**  |
| Cat1         | 80%       |
| Cat2         | 12%       |
| Cat3         | 3%        |
| Cat4         | 1%        |
| Cat5         | 4%        |

Let(s say I would like to rank all Cat5 as follows :

N°1 | Group A | Cat5 | 30%
N°2 | Group B | Cat5 | 4%
etc.

Comment: Not in comments, in your question. (Edit option)